# Why isn't this c client able to read data sent by this c server if the latter calls the write system call twice?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, tcpserver

How come this client is only able to read data sent from the first server write system call ? It correctly reads the data sent by the first write, but not with the second one...

Here's the client :

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define PORT 1025
#define SA struct sockaddr

int main(){


int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
//CREATE SOCKET
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

char buff[1024];
while( (read(sockfd, buff,sizeof(buff))) > 0){
printf("%s\n",buff);
}

close(sockfd);

return 0;

}
```

And here is the server :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define PORT 1025


int main(){


 int sockfd, connfd;
 unsigned int len;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

//SOCKET CREATION
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
//BIND
if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
//LISTEN
if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

for(;;){

len = sizeof(cli);

connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);


if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
char buff[]="Hi";
char buff2[]="More data sent..\n";

write(connfd,buff,sizeof(buff)); //work
write(connfd,buff2,sizeof(buff2)); //doesn't work


close(connfd);
}


return 0;

}
```

I also noticed it works if I put the second write inside a loop that requires a certain amount of time. For example :

```
long max=0;
while(max<1000000000){

//second write works
write(......);

}
```

Could someone give an explanation of why write behaves like that and what's going on under the hood ?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: Common error. You are assuming that each `read` will get exactly the content of one corresponding `write`. That is not guaranteed to be the case with streaming protocols like TCP. Each `read` can get the data from part of a single `write` or from a whole `write` or from multiple `write`s. In your case when you do two `write` calls back to back it is likely the client will read both writes in one go. Which means the client `buff` will contain two strings. Which you won't be able to see as `printf` with `%s` will only print the first string.

Comment: You calling `write()` 1000000000 times?

Comment: Need to check the return value of `read` to know exactly how much it has read. And need to handle reads which contain partial and/or multiple "messages". That is you need to parse the data for message boundaries (the NUL character in this case).

Comment: Also, check the return value from `write()`. The result of all i/o functions should be checked.

Comment: Notice that the while loop has been written quite roughly. I should have added a break and an increment operator for the counter....

Comment: @Kode1000 How do you know it doesn't work?